# replaceWith() does not return tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried searching this on other questions as well but I don't seem to understand this method. I am trying to create a header on top of an image and the script should reduce the length of the text if it is longer than 40 characters and add 3 dots at the end of the string

```
let content = document.getElementById('videoText');
let valuare = content.innerHTML;
let lungime = valuare.length;

if( lungime > 40){
    let newValuare = valuare.substring(0, 40) + " ...";
    console.log(newValuare);
    content.replaceWith('<span>' + newValuare.text() + '</span>');
}
```

In the console log, the text is exactly how I want it however the browser does not display anything in this form as it inquires that `newValuare.text()` is not a function and if I remove the `.text()`method it displays but without the span tags which are displayed as strings. 
I tried without quoting them without the `'<span>'`tags but it displays just a text, without tags.

How can I add the specific text between tags.

```
<img src="video1.jpg" alt="">
 <div class="video-text">
  <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
   <span>1:12</span>
   <span id="videoText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptate tempore quaerat delectus, alias praesentium magni ullam voluptatibus. Minima, corrupti officiis illum dicta pariatur obcaecati sed atque voluptate sapiente aliquid modi!
                Enim doloribus officiis nulla velit dignissimos nam, nisi laboriosam placeat omnis veritatis? Aspernatur eveniet dolorum voluptates, odit ut hic temporibus animi, soluta nesciunt laudantium autem, quidem incidunt reiciendis rerum neque?
                Sequi, laborum nam deserunt delectus ipsum expedita maxime reiciendis distinctio nesciunt debitis nihil tempora quasi at aliquam commodi? Dolores, officiis. Voluptatibus odio magni repudiandae dolore ipsam accusantium iure dolores vero.
                Laboriosam quas tempore architecto voluptatum, incidunt itaque fugit maxime quisquam nesciunt accusantium? Qui repudiandae nemo rerum accusamus illo, excepturi sequi repellat iure non ipsam reprehenderit voluptates minus maiores enim natus!</span>
              </div>
```

Comment: Post the ```HTML``` code as well..

Comment: *but it displays just a text, without text*??

Comment: without tags i wanted to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `innerHtml` use `textContent` to fetch the text of the element.

Then you can replace the text inside `if` condition like,

```
content.textContent = newValuare;
```

And the snippet as follows,

```js
let content = document.getElementById('videoText');
let valuare = content.textContent;
let lungime = valuare.length;

if( lungime > 40){
    let newValuare = valuare.substring(0, 40) + " ...";
    content.textContent = newValuare;
}
```

```html
 <div class="video-text">
  <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
   <span>1:12</span>
   <span id="videoText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptate tempore quaerat delectus, alias praesentium magni ullam voluptatibus. Minima, corrupti officiis illum dicta pariatur obcaecati sed atque voluptate sapiente aliquid modi!
                Enim doloribus officiis nulla velit dignissimos nam, nisi laboriosam placeat omnis veritatis? Aspernatur eveniet dolorum voluptates, odit ut hic temporibus animi, soluta nesciunt laudantium autem, quidem incidunt reiciendis rerum neque?
                Sequi, laborum nam deserunt delectus ipsum expedita maxime reiciendis distinctio nesciunt debitis nihil tempora quasi at aliquam commodi? Dolores, officiis. Voluptatibus odio magni repudiandae dolore ipsam accusantium iure dolores vero.
                Laboriosam quas tempore architecto voluptatum, incidunt itaque fugit maxime quisquam nesciunt accusantium? Qui repudiandae nemo rerum accusamus illo, excepturi sequi repellat iure non ipsam reprehenderit voluptates minus maiores enim natus!</span>
              </div>
```

Comment: @NeaguClaudiuAlexandru, If you need to replace any text alone then use ```textContent``` and only use ```innerHtml``` if you need to change it with some ```HTML``` content.. And if it solves your issue then feel free to accept the answer..